# Google Graph DataTable + Piechart styling

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Trying to set the colour of each slice of the pie chart via the `dataTable.addRow`

Using the following code this should work apparently:

```
//[...]
dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
dataTable.addRow([graphData[i], parseFloat(graphData[i + 1]), 'color: #000000;      fill-color:#000000'
//[...]
```

As per the style section found here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available

Does anyone have any examples of doing this with a pie chart?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for a `PieChart`, the only optional role available is [tooltip](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole).

but you can use the `colors` configuration option, see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Category', 'Hours'],
        ['Commute',   2],
        ['Eat',       2],
        ['Sleep',     6]
      ]),
      {
        colors: ['cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow'],
        pieSliceTextStyle: {
          color: 'black'
        }
      }
    );
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
```